# how to display questions to user and compare them using "if" "else" statements expert system django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I have stored the rules in database in form of questions and want to ask questions by user and then conclude to a result.
I want questions to be displayed on user's screen with yes or no option and ask further questions according to the choices. i am unable to find a solution that how should i compare user input from front end with backend (django)
so far i have tried

**views.py**

```
def fetch_rules(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        issueid=request.POST['issueid']
        rules=Rules.objects.all().filter(parentissue=issueid)
        return render(request,"questions.html",{"rules":rules})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content%}
<div class="questionwrapper">
    {% for rul in rules %}
<div class="question">
    <h1>{{rul.question}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="solution"> 
<p>{{rul.solution}}</p>

</div>

<p style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;">Your issue solved?</p>
<div class="question_btns">
    <a id="yes_q"  >Yes</a>
    <a id="no_q"  >No</a>
</div>
{%endfor%}
</div>
{% endblock %}[![My template][1]][1]
```

currently template shows all the questions but i want to display once at a time and then display one after another according to the user's choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add content dynamically, you must use front-end technology. All you have to do is hide the questions using CSS `display:none`,then make onclick events on the buttons and a simple JS script will change the display of a specific child `display:nth-child(n):inline-block`

You may also do somethink similar using objects id, for example:

```py
<div class="question" data-id={{rul.question.id}}>
    <h1>{{rul.question}}</h1>
</div>
```

And now you can sort or display objects with data-id and JavaScript